# Host ASP.NET website on IIS in my laptop to share with colleagues?

Tags: vpn, hosting, asp.net, website

I am trying to share my ASP website with my colleagues so that I can receive their feedback.

I can access the project by using both these methods in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8125/
http://pc_hostname:8125/
```

How can other people on my work network/VPN access my pc's port 8125?

If so, then what do i need to do?

I am using IIS 7.5 and here are my firwall settings:
http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1447/firewallx.jpg

Sorry can't upload image directly due to no reputation

Comment: We need more information, such as what webserver you're using, because some servers, like Cassini, do not allow external connections. And then there's also your firewall configuration.

Comment: Yegods! You're connected to a public network without a firewall?!

Comment: So - is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just push your site to [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) or [Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/) - they both have free options and getting started is super simple. That way, you site is public on the web and your colleagues can try it out. Much easier than mucking around with VPN and firewalls and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is diagnosing the problem. So far your post doesn't provide much in the way of diagnostic info, but the first step is to ensure that both machines (i.e. yours and theirs) can see each other, this is done by pinging them. Note that Windows Firewall by default blocks ICMP ping, so you need to manually enable it. I won't describe how to enable ICMP ping in this post, but you can easily find it on the web.

Make sure your computer's name is resolvable from the other machine - if it's a NetBIOS name and your network doesn't have DNS registration for machine names then this might be a culprit - I personally find the NetBIOS experience in Windows to be very lacking, I don't know why we don't have anything like Apple's Bonjour/mDNS service. Use a command like `nslookup` or even `ping` to ensure the name is being resolved fine.

We've already established that you've disabled your local Windows Firewall, so that can be removed from the problem-space.

After you've established the machines can see and talk to each other, look at your IIS configuration and see what the bindings of the website are (open IIS, select the website, and click on "Bindings" on the right side of the screen). Ensure that it's bound to `0.0.0.0` (aka "All unassigned IP addresses") and that there aren't any other sites bound to your machine's address.

If that doesn't work, then we can't help you more without more information from you, like specific error messages.

Comment: Thanks for all that info - I think it would be better of using some kind of free hosting site - it would save me a lot of time!